# Log to remote clients with server side filtering using NLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I have a console application running on a server that produces a lot of logging (NLog is used for this). I want to be able to listen in on the logging remotely. I could use the network logging type, but I want to reduce bandwidth so I want to apply filtering on the server side so that only filtered logging is sent to the client.

I could create predefined logging targets on the server and listen in on those, but that's not good enough. The client needs to be able to specify the filter. Multiple clients should be able to listen in on the logging.

Is there any way to get this type of functionality working out of the box with NLog? Or would I need to create a custom way of doing this with a subscriber list of some sort?

Comment: The "filter" you are talking about is called `LogLevel`. Configure the log level of your messages so that if the client subscribes to `Info` level then they hear what they need to hear. Hide the noise a lower levels like `Debug` and `Trace`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is no 'out of box' solutions, but you may write a custom `Target`:

For example:

```
public class MySuperTarget : TargetWithLayout 
{ 
    public MySuperTarget()
    {
    }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent) 
    { 
        // 1. Filter LogEventInfo 
        // 2. Send to clients
    } 
}
```

More info here: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-Target